# Error loading my script (Google Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have made a script that works in a Google Chrome extension. I quickly explained:
There is an online game called Dragonbound. What the script does is calculate the force with which you must shoot to the opponent. Ok I have tried to accommodate my script on an external server and apparently loaded but not executed ("loading"). I think the fault may be in the code (I used the javascript of the videogame to create my script). Deputy the original code, the json and the js that makes the call to the external scripts:

[Main Javascript in Codeviewer](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2c1d)

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "DragonBound Aimbot 2.0",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "DragonBound Aimbot Hack - HTML5",
   "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
   "permissions": ["tabs", "notifications", "http://*.dropbox.com/u/91461506/*", "https://*.dropbox.com/u/91461506/*"],
   "background": { "page": "background.html", "persistent" : false },
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*.dragonbound.net/*","http://*.dropbox.com/u/91461506/*"],
      "js": ["jquery2.js","DragonBoundAimbot.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "icons": {"16": "16.png", "48": "48.png", "128": "128.png"},
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "ranks/*","48.png"
  ],
  "homepage_url" : "http://www.dropbox.com"
}
```

-Code makes the call for external scripts:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({type:"init"},function(response){

    if(response.ingame){
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({id:"loading",type:"notification2",text:["Loading","Loading scripts from dropbox.com..."]}, function(response) {});
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({type:"loadscript",url:'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/91461506/prueba2.js',cache:false}, function(response) {
            if(response.type == 1){
                eval(response.scriptcontent);

            }else if(response.type == 0){
                chrome.extension.sendRequest({id:"loading",type:"closenotification2"}, function(response) {})
                chrome.extension.sendRequest({id:"errorloading",time:0,type:"notification2",text:["Error","Failed to load the script, try again later"]}, function(response) {});
            }
        });
    }else{
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({type:"loadscript",url:'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/91461506/page.js',cache:false}, function(response) {
            if(response.type == 1){
                eval(response.scriptcontent);
                PAGEDBA.init();
            }else if(response.type == 0){

            }
        });
    }
});
```

I've uploaded the extension of Google Chrome and the extension uncompressed:
[Extension of Chrome .CRX](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/91461506/Testing.crx)

[Estension uncompressed .ZIP](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/91461506/Testing.zip)

[image: Preview]
[image: Preview 2]

The link of the webpage of the videogame is [DragonBound.net](http://dragonbound.net)

Answer (score 1):

You use `eval()`, but `eval()` is disabled in chrome-extensions.

http://developer.chrome.com/apps/sandboxingEval.html

Comment: The easiest solution to this specific case would be to simply include the files you're trying to load in the extension itself.